# Using argon2 encryption in php 7.3 without recompiling

Tags: php

I want to encrypt passwords using argon2 in php 7.3, but the problem is that I have to recompile php with
`—with-password-argon2` flag.
The issue is that the current hosting provider doesn't support this. Is there any way to use argon2 in php without recompiling or should I just use bcrypt?

Comment: Short answer: just use bcrypt

Comment: See this from people that know their way around security: https://github.com/paragonie/sodium_compat#features-excluded-from-this-polyfill

Comment: @deceze Thanks, if you post this as an answer, I can choose it as a selected one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there *is* a [polyfill](https://github.com/paragonie/sodium_compat) for [libsodium](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/), a library for various cryptographic algorithms, and [they state](https://github.com/paragonie/sodium_compat#features-excluded-from-this-polyfill):

> It's not feasible to polyfill scrypt or Argon2 into PHP and get reasonable performance. Users would feel motivated to select parameters that downgrade security to avoid denial of service (DoS) attacks.
>
> The only winning move is not to play.

So, no, a pure PHP solution is apparently infeasible. You will need to be able to install *some* native library in some form or another.

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 7.2, [Sodium](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sodium.php) is usually bundled with PHP. This library provides high-level function for cryptography (encryption, signature, hash,...).

It provides the `sodium_crypto_pwhash_str` function ([source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sodium-crypto-pwhash-str.php)) that uses argon2, and is Sodium is indeed bundled, you shouldn't need to recompile PHP. You should use the parameters given for time and memory options. With a moderate security setting I had this output : `$argon2id$v=19$m=262144,t=3,p=1$cH0L6kab+fCGHBE3fEw2bw$leS9TBiPOq1gEGg+O6PxAn/O7XXyVnRLs6ANcHHXfCIroot@vps531354:`

Comment: According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/sodium.installation.php, you still need to compile php with sodium support and after checking hosting provider's php configuration, it wasn't included

Comment: I guess that your provider has a very stripped down PHP version, as Unix packets (e.g. Debian) have all of this by default, and that you should then use more "standard" functions as bcrypt... On a side note, is changing of provider an option? This one seems really limited.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing a provider is not an option.